# SHA-256 compression functions without padding

Tags: hash, sha-256

Looking at the example of the null input (512 bits), it takes as input:

> input (Hex):
> 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Since it's exactly 512 bits, there is no splitting and no padding. But from online calculators or golang code, I would obtain the sha-256 hash of the null input to be:

> online calculator output (Hex):
> f5a5fd42d16a20302798ef6ed309979b43003d2320d9f0e8ea9831a92759fb4b

However, in several libraries e.g.[kobigurk](https://gist.github.com/kobigurk/b7777aec554bd40f97f18777cf7367a5#file-gistfile1-txt-L1) or [SCALA MAMBA](https://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/%7Ensmart/MPC/sha-256-test.txt) etc., the expected value should be:

> library (Hex): da5698be17b9b46962335799779fbeca8ce5d491c0d26243bafef9ea1837a9d8

I chose null input precisely as 512 bits without padding. What could be the problem?

Comment: The padding is always applied no matter the size of the input.

Comment: Could you provide some references? How would the padding apply if the input is only 512 bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer;**

You are mixing the compression function and the hash function. Both pages/libraries are true on their context!

---

**Extended answer**

SHA-256 like the other hash algorithms is always padded and it is defined in [NIST.FIPS.180-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf)

> Suppose the length of the message $M$, in bits, $\ell$ is bits. Append the bit `1` to the end of the message, followed by `k` zero bits, where `k` is the smallest non-negative solution to the equation
> $$\ell +1 + k \equiv 448 \bmod 512$$ Then append the 64-bit block that is equal to the number $\ell$ expressed using a binary representation

So 512 zeros bits in SHA-256 will have 447 zeros ($k$ part);

$$\text{Padded_Message} =\underbrace{\texttt{000...00}}_{512-zeros}||\texttt{1}||\underbrace{\texttt{000...00}}_{447-zeros}||\underbrace{\texttt{leng encoding}}_{64-bit}$$

If you really want to test some inputs, make sure that they are correct on the NIST's test vectors defined in [Cryptographic Algorithm Validation Program - Hash functions](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/Secure-Hashing)

For padding, as usual, is not related to the user. The libraries handle the padding for the users.

> Since it's exactly 512 bits, there is no splitting and no padding. But from online calculators or golang code, I would obtain the sha-256 hash of the null input to be:

As mentioned above, padding is always defined. It is part of the SHA-256 hash algorithm.

Your input is not null input, it is 512-bit zero input. NIST provides the length zero test vector and it's result as

> Len = 0
> Msg = 00
> MD = e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

Testing your input on [sha256algorithm.com](https://sha256algorithm.com/) produces

`f5a5fd42d16a20302798ef6ed309979b43003d2320d9f0e8ea9831a92759fb4b`

I've tested this page on some NIST test vector's too.

The link you provides as [SCALA MAMBA](https://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/%7Ensmart/MPC/sha-256-test.txt) mentions as;

> Output: Chaining values after compressing input block (in the same format as the digest would be returned)
> IMPORTANT: These are NOT test vectors for the complete SHA-256 hash function, as the padding rules are ignored

This is the output of the first compression function. This can be verified on the [sha256algorithm.com](https://sha256algorithm.com/) if you stop on the 164th step. Put your mouse on the initial values and you will get the hex value;

`da5698be17b...`

This is the same on the other link to; given as *sha256 compression test vectors*.

Remember the output of the compression function is the initial value of the next compression function if needed. If not needed, then it is the output of the SHA-256. The first initial values are given;

> These words represent the first thirty-two bits of the fractional parts of the cube roots of the first sixty-four prime numbers

as a [nothing-up-im-my-sleeve-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing-up-my-sleeve_number) though this is psychological.

Comment: thanks! this is really helpful.

Comment: a follow-up question: In which step can I find out the initial hash value H(0) for the 1st block in the provided website [sha256algorithm.com](https://sha256algorithm.com/)? It seems that the initial hash value for 1st block is not provided.

Comment: Look at step 50...